# how to replace string with different replacement in java

Tags: java, regex

Now I have a String like this

```
it is #1, or #2, or #3
```

I want to transfer it to this:

```
it is < a href="/1">#1< /a>, or #< a href="/2">#2< /a>, or < a href="/3">#3< /a>
```

So I want to replace the word "#{num}" to "< a href="/{num}">#{num}< /a>"

What shall I do?

Comment: Do you want `href="/1"` in all 3 cases?

Comment: sorry, I modified it now

Comment: Thanks for update, posted an answer with demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Java code should work:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("(?<!>)#(\\d+)(?!<)", "<a href=\"/$1\">#$1</a>");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jA3eB3/1)

**PS:** I have added lookaheads to make sure we don't replace a string with hyperlinks like: `it is <a href="/1">#1</a>` (check demo link for an example).

Comment: +1. I was thinking of doing this then decided to go down the `Matcher.appendReplacement` route - can't quite remember why. This is much shorter!

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group to capture the `#` along with the following number.

Regex:

```
(#(\\d+))
```

Replacement string:

```
< a href="/$2">$1< /a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/26)

```
String str = "it is #1, or #2, or #3";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(#(\\d+))", "< a href=\"/$2\">$1< /a>"));
```

Output:

```
it is < a href="/1">#1< /a>, or < a href="/2">#2< /a>, or < a href="/3">#3< /a>
```

Comment: sorry, but i want the string to be < a href="/{num}">#{num}< /a>

Comment: thank you for your answer , it is my fault.  I am sorry